# Where is saved login name saved in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-live-messenger

When I sign in again to msn, yahoo messenger, chat program etc. the login name is saved, and I only need to type in password to proceed to login.

Where are these saved msn, yahoo messenger login name saved to in the harddrive?

Answer (score 1):

For MSN Messenger:

```
Start -> Run -> "control userpasswords2" (without the quotes) -> OK -> Advanced tab -> Click on "Manage Passwords"
```

Comment: seems doesn't work for me. It ends up searching for files name "control userpasswords2"

Comment: You need to type "control userpasswords2" into the run box, but don't type the quotes.